# Did Byomkesh Bakshi ever fight on screen?

Tags: byomkesh-bakshi

[**Byomkesh Bakshi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byomkesh_Bakshi) is a detective like Sherlock Holmes. Both have many similarities. Based on him was the TV show [**Byomkesh Bakshi**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0157217/) which ran from 1993-1997 on Indian channel DD National spanning 34 episodes in two seasons.

Byomkesh is mostly calm in many stories. According to IMDb:

> An intelligent detective from Kolkata solves many mystery that unsolved by police **without any weapons**.

But has he ever used a weapon or at least kicked or punched someone throughout the series?

Comment: @close-voters See, this isn't really an identification question.

Comment: No, he just solve the case but yes sometime we catch the person if some one try to run n mostly at the end when case approx near about to solve police always present there so he was not need  weapon according to serial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have started (29 Nov 2018) to watch some of the episodes in random order.

In season 2 ep 18, Byomkesh tackles and captures culprit he is attacked from back.

In season 2 ep 20, Byomkesh intercepts culprit red-handed and hits him with a torch in his hand.

It's not active fighting like Sherlock Holmes but it is some amount of violence Byomkesh indulges in, suggesting that he does not back off from a fight.